# Sefira Reminder

Tags: product-recommendation, sefirat-ha-omer

Does anyone know of a service that emails you a sefirah reminder,better yet a text ,for free?

Comment: Google is your friend: http://bit.ly/elhwHG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well... see: http://www.tizkor.com/sefira

Answer (score 2):

Text the name of your cellphone carrier to 616-613-OMER.

Comment: And what will happen? (You'll get a reminder each night at sunset in your area code, perhaps?) Anyway, welcome to the site. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.haomer.org/ - here you can get email or SMS (in Israel) notifications